# What does the "Flick only" setting of iPad's Japanese keyboard do?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, japanese

I've been using the Japanese keyboard layout for a while, but only recently I have noticed there are two options for the software keyboard layout, namely "Kana" and "Flick only". Can anybody tell me what the difference is, since they look and behave identical, as far as I can tell.

This is on a 1st generation iPad running iOS 5.1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's like this: With the "Kana" setting, you can reach the different kana of one group by either "flicking" in different directions, or by repeatedly tapping one kana. With the "flick only" setting, only the flicking works, not the tapping.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but it was one of the first results I got on Google

"Kana" shows a special keyboard with hiragana characters instead of the English letters. The iPad keyboard will show a grid with all the characters. The iPhone keyboard groups them by consonant to have less on-screen keys, and sets a direction for each vowel. You can either hold and flick in a given direction or repeatedly tap to get the desired characters (just like old 2000 phones)

"Flick only" is an option that only on iPhones or iPhone apps running on an iPad (like Instagram) because that's the only way to show the iPhone keyboard on an iPad, and it deactivates the option to tap repeatedly, only allowing you to type characters by flicking